DataGridView selection doesn't work when fast checking a CheckBoxColumn
I have a problem with my Windows Forms .NET Framework 4.8.1 project. I try to make a DataGridView with multiple DataGridViewCheckBoxColumns and bind them together so when I check one CheckBox the other will change its' state as well. I got it to work but it only works when I click once and wait a little, if I try to click faster the other CheckBox stays untouched.
Both of those columns have "true" set for trueValue and "false" for falseValue.
Here is my code for the current moment:
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillDGV();
        }

        private void FillDGV() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            }
        }
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick( object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e ) {
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit( DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit );
            if (e.RowIndex != -1 ) {
                if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell) {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[ e.RowIndex ].Cells[4].Value = cell.Value;
                }
            }
               
            
        }
    }
}

The application looks like that:
enter image description here
I've tried to use CellDirtyStateChanged event but it didn't work.

I'd suggest preventing double-click from being allowed on a CheckBoxCell. You can use a bool Field, set it to true in CellMouseDown when e.Clicks > 1, then set it back to false in CellMouseUp. Check the value of this Field in CellContentClick, return when it's true. You could also use a Custom Control derived from DataGridView, intercept WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK and override OnCellMouseDown() -- BTW, the code you have here doesn't do what you said it should do

Also, use [DataGridView].EndEndit() instead of [DataGridView].CommitEdit( DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit) (it ends up doing ~the same thing, but it's more involved and easier to remember) and check the value of e.ColumnIndex as well as e.RowIndex

@Jimi thank you, the custom control works well
